# Updating pivot table data source after copying from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that copies a *pivot table* and its original source data in *Workbook A* to *Workbook B*. Is there a way to update the source data via Excel VBA that takes information from *Workbook B ("fields")* instead of *Workbook A*?

This is the code for identifying workbook B:

```
Dim WrkbookB As Workbook
Set WrkbookB = ActiveWorkbook
```

This is the code for importing the *pivot table (in Sheet1)* and original source data *("Fields") in Workbook A*:

```
Dim WrkbookA As Workbook
folder = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel.xlsx (*.xlsx), *.xlsx," & _
        "Excel.xls (*xls), *xls", 1, "Select Workbook A")
Set WrkbookA= Workbooks.Open(Filename:=folder)
WrkbookA.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=WrkbookB.Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"
WrkbookA.Sheets("Fields").Copy After:=WrkbookB.Sheets(1)
WrkbookA.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Any help on how to change the data source is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A good suggestion is to avoid using any `Active` properties and stick to either specifying workbooks by name and worksheets by name or index number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming you have successfully imported the sheets.
What you need is to *change the pivot cache* and we have a method to do that.
Before that, you need to identify the source range of the data:

```
Dim sourceRange As String
'/* this is a short cut but you can improve this, dynamically getting your source */
sourceRange = WrkbookB.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Address(, , xlR1C1, True)
```

Once you have the source, you need to create the cache:

```
With Sheets("Field") '/* this is in Workbook B */
  .PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache WrkbookB. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=sourceRange)
End With
```

I used `PivotTables(1)` assuming you only have 1 *pivot table* in *Fields* sheet.
 If not, you will have to replace it with the target *pivot table* name.